# Security Onion - possible infection

Tags: security, malware

I recently installed a Security Onion virtual machine with the Oracle Virtual Box. The host machine is Ubuntu 16.04.
As part of the IntroductionWalkthrough (https://github.com/Security-Onion-Solutions/security-onion/wiki/IntroductionWalkthrough) I replayed some malicious packets in Security Onion without disabling the wireless connection.
I am now wondering if this could have had any negative effect on my Ubuntu machine and how can I ensure the machine is not infected.

Comment: Not familiar with Security Onion, neither I have time to investigate in details, sorry. But, if you haven't used `bridged` network for connecting you should be safe, as packets will be unable to reach you. However, running `rkhunter` or `clamav` wouldn't harm.

Answer (score 0):

Replaying packets will not cause any negative effect on your Ubuntu machine. Also your machine will not be infected.  The malicious packets that were replayed were unique to that network and sessions that were currently active and wouldn't infect your PC.  Refer to how a 3-way handshake and sessions are managed in the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you expand on this, perhaps citing a reference so that other users could gain a more thorough understanding of what you are saying?